# How to write dynamic URL in Jquery script

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a table with data using jquery and accessing a php database through a URL. It works when i predefine the input but I can't figure out how to get this to work with the input.

**Q: What is the correct URL in the script to make it work with the input field?**

Database URL: https://webservice.informatik.umu.se/webservice_livsmedel/getlivsmedel.php

(The commented script works, but that is not the URL I am supposed to use.)

**IMPORTANT! I am only allowed to make changes in the js-file!**

All help would be more than welcome! :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Nutrition table</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Uppgift 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

    <div class="search-template">
        <h1>Sökning av livsmedel</h1>

        <form class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="search-word">Livsmedel</label>
                <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search-word" placeholder="t ex 
makaroner">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="sok-button">Sök</button>
        </form>
        <table id="search-table" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Livsmedel</th>
                    <th>Energi (kcal/100g)</th>
                    <th>Kolhydrater</th>
                    <th>Protein</th>
                    <th>Fett</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/getLivsmedelsData.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
$( "#sok-button" ).click(function() {

//$('#search-word').on('change paste keyup', function () {
//Empty content in list
$('#resultat').empty();
// Gets content from input
var forNamnStr = $('#search-word').val();

//If there is content (length is more than 0)
if (forNamnStr.length > 0) {
    //Performs a question to the web service
 `$.ajax({
        //url: "https://webservice.informatik.umu.se/webservice_persondb/persondb.php",
        url: "https://webservice.informatik.umu.se/webservice_livsmedel/getlivsmedel.php? 
namn=bacon&callback=getLivsmedel",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            limit: 15,
            name: forNamnStr
        },
        // If respons is successful
        success: function (response) {
            var person = response.personer;
            var livsmedel = response.livsmedel;
            // Cycle through all person objects
            //person.forEach(function (namn) {
            livsmedel.forEach(function (nutrition) {
                
                //Add li-element to ul-element with id=resultat
                //$('tbody').append('<li>' + namn.fnamn + ' ' + namn.enamn + '</li>');
                $('tbody').append('<li>' + nutrition.protein + ' ' + nutrition.fett + 
'</li>');
                
            });

        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to pass the #search-word input field value as the `namn=` parameter in the url,

You can just use concatenation like

```
$.ajax({        
        url: "https://webservice.informatik.umu.se/webservice_livsmedel/getlivsmedel.php? 
namn=" + forNamnStr + "&callback=getLivsmedel",
.....
}
```

Note: any values passed with the `data:` property in the $.ajax call, will also be appended to the url as `&key=value` (ie., it will not check for duplicates).
So either pass in the `data:` property or pass directly in the url using concatenation.

Comment: Thanks a million for helping me out, it worked perfectly.